# Trying to loop through data from JSON in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to pull out data from a JSON I've extracted using the following code:

```
library(jsonlite) 

Data_GW_1 <- fromJSON("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/event/1/live")

for(i in 1:5)
    {  
        Data_GW_1_points <- c(Data_GW_1_points, Data_GW_1$elements$[i]$stats$total_points)
    }
```

In words what I'm trying to do with this code is to loop five times through the data creating a vector.

Hope this sounds clear,
OilFerry

Edit:

Thank you for your help earlier. I think its better to build on my previous question instead of starting a new thread.

What I'm trying to achieve is to fetch the total points data for each player per game week in the fantasy premier league and construct it in the following way with a dataframe or a matrix:

```
             Player_name_1   Player_name_2   ...   Player_name_n
Gameweek_1
Gameweek_2
...
Gameweek_m
```

I'm using the following data sources:
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/event/[Gameweek]/live 
for the points per player per Gameweek
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static 
for the id and number of each player

I've been using the following code to fetch the points for each player for gameweeks 1 and 2 but don't understand why there is a difference in number of items -> Gameweek1 has 524 and Gameweek has 537.

I'm also trying to wrap my mind around how to join the id and/or names of the players from the bootstrap-static data source with the data from the event data source to create the data frame or matrix demonstrated above.

```
##loading the jsonlite package
library(jsonlite)  

##Fetshing points per player for Gameweek 1 and 2
Data_GW_1 <- fromJSON("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/event/1/live")
points_GW1 <- sapply(Data_GW_1$elements, function(x) x$stats$total_points, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

Data_GW_2 <- fromJSON("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/event/2/live")
points_GW2 <- sapply(Data_GW_2$elements, function(x) x$stats$total_points, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

##Creating names before joining data
GW1_names <- "Gameweek 1"
GW2_names <- "Gameweek 2"

##Creating a dataframe from the data with names
df <- data.frame(points_GW1,points_GW2)
names(df) <- c(GW1_names, GW2_names)
print(df)

##Getting the following error message
Error in data.frame(points_GW1, points_GW2) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 524, 537
> names(df) <- c(GW1_names, GW2_names)
Error in names(df) <- c(GW1_names, GW2_names) : 
  names() applied to a non-vector
> print(df)
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
  if (missing(ncp)) 
    .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
  else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000428a038>
  <environment: namespace:stats>
```

Hope this makes some sense :)

Comment: Your example code is not "looping 5 times through the data". It is moving through the first 5 elements of the list `Data_GW_1$elements`. Is that what you want to do: just get the first 5 values for `total_points ` ?

Comment: Data_GW_1$elements$1

Comment: `sapply(Data_GW_1$elements, function(x){ x[['stats']][['total_points']]})` to get a vector of all the points.

Comment: I had a similar suggestion: `sapply(Data_GW_1$elements, function(x) x$stats$total_points, USE.NAMES = FALSE)`. If that's what you want, one of us can post it as answer :)

Comment: sorry hit enter for mistake:
This is how I understand the data
'Data_GW_1$elements$1$stats$total_points' is the data from Game week number 1 for player number 1. Therefore I want to extract data for every player in the league, 500 times.

Comment: Both suggestions will generate a vector of 524 values for `total_points`. Is that the required output? If not, define precisely what is.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you guys so much for your help and very swift response. What a great first time experience of using this site.